# encrypting and decrypting with a simple substitution cipher

Tags: c#, cryptography, encryption

trying to create a simple substitution cipher,my program is working quite alright but its not encrypting or decrypting numbers. I really do not know what I should add to my code so that it works properly ...any ideas???
this is my code

```
namespace yaba
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string encrypt = tboxIO.Text;
            encrypt.ToLower();


            bool tbNull = tboxIO.Text == "";

            if (tbNull)
                MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to encrypt.");

            else
            {
                char[] array = encrypt.ToCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    int num = (int)array[i];
                    if (num >= 'a' && num <= 'z')
                    {
                        num += Convert.ToInt32(tbShift.Text);
                        if (num > 'z')
                        {
                            num = num - 26;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (num >= 'A' && num <= 'Z')
                    {
                        num += Convert.ToInt32(tbShift.Text);
                        if (num > 'Z')
                        {
                            num = num - 26;
                        }
                    }
                    array[i] = (char)num;
                }
                lblIO.Text = "Encrypted Message";
                tboxIO.Text = new string(array).ToLower();
            }

            tboxIO.Copy();
        }

        private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string decrypt = tboxIO.Text;
            decrypt.ToLower();

            bool tbNull = tboxIO.Text == "";

            if (tbNull)
                MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to decrypt.");

            else
            {
                char[] array = decrypt.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    int num = (int)array[i];
                    if (num >= 'a' && num <= 'z')
                    {
                        num -= Convert.ToInt32(tbShift.Text);
                        if (num > 'z')
                            num = num - 26;

                        if (num < 'a')
                            num = num + 26;
                    }
                    else if (num >= 'A' && num <= 'Z')
                    {
                        num -= Convert.ToInt32(tbShift.Text);
                        if (num > 'Z')
                            num = num - 26;

                        if (num < 'A')
                            num = num + 26;
                    }
                    array[i] = (char)num;
                }
                lblIO.Text = "Decrypted Message";
                tboxIO.Text = new string(array).ToUpper();
            }

            tboxIO.Copy();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hehe");
        }

        private void tboxIO_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tboxIO.SelectAll();
            tboxIO.Copy();
        }

        private void tbShift_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tbShift.SelectAll();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by what logic *do* you want to encrypt numbers? Should they also be shifted `Convert.ToInt32(tbShift.Text)` times? Then you could add another `else if` with `(num >= '0' && num <= '9')` and do the same thing (with +/- 10 instead of +/- 26).

You need to be aware though, that you might go around two or even three times, depending on how much you want to shift by. And I hope you somehow made sure that `tbShift.Text` can only(!) have numbers not higher than 26.

But *you* need to know how you want to encrypt/decrypt numbers and tell us, so we even have a chance of helping you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code like this. You shouldn't use ToLower.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string myText = "MusLum";
        string encrypted = "";
        string decrypted = "";
        char shift = 'a';
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Encrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string encrypt = myText;

            bool tbNull = myText == "";

            if (tbNull)
                MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to encrypt.");

            else
            {
                char[] array = encrypt.ToCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    int num = (int)array[i];
                    if (num >= 'a' && num <= 'z')
                    {

                        num += (Convert.ToInt32(shift.ToString().ToLower()[0]) - Convert.ToInt32('a')+1);

                        if (num > 'z')
                        {
                            num = num - 26;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (num >= 'A' && num <= 'Z')
                    {
                        num += (Convert.ToInt32(shift.ToString().ToUpper()[0]) - Convert.ToInt32('A')+1);

                        if (num > 'Z')
                        {
                            num = num - 26;
                        }
                    }
                    array[i] = (char)num;
                }

                encrypted = new string(array);
            }


        }

        private void Decrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string decrypt = encrypted;


            bool tbNull = encrypted == "";

            if (tbNull)
                MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to decrypt.");

            else
            {
                char[] array = encrypted.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    int num = (int)array[i];
                    if (num >= 'a' && num <= 'z')
                    {
                        num -= (Convert.ToInt32(shift.ToString().ToLower()[0]) - Convert.ToInt32('a')+1);

                        if (num > 'z')
                            num = num - 26;

                        if (num < 'a')
                            num = num + 26;
                    }
                    else if (num >= 'A' && num <= 'Z')
                    {
                        num -= (Convert.ToInt32(shift.ToString().ToUpper()[0]) - Convert.ToInt32('A')+1);

                        if (num > 'Z')
                            num = num - 26;

                        if (num < 'A')
                            num = num + 26;
                    }
                    array[i] = (char)num;
                }

                decrypted = new string(array);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're explicitly saying that you only want to encrypt upper and lower case letters, so no, numbers are not encrypted.

Also (unrelated) your calls to ToLower are unrewarding as ToLower is a function and you do not assign the result to anything.